geo nodes Start/Stop Attribute
Hello i want to make a geo node setup where we define a Start and End frame and get an attribute value which starts from 0 at start frame then stop at certain value let's say 10 and just a few frames before End frame start coming down from 10 to 0

i tried making this with simulation nodes just adding 1 to a named attribute and using the skip checkbox for making sim start at the given start frame

Then i tried stacking another for End frame but didn't work


The simulation zone method would work, but since this can be easily expressed with math nodes, I would choose the none-simulated approach.

Result

